# How do I give access to my partner to my local MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

My partner and I are using MySQL, Express, and Node while working with a database that is setup on my local machine using MySQL workbench. Below is the code I use to connect to the database.

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '****',
    database: 'events',
    port: '3306'
})
```

We tried for a little bit to fix the issue but didn't figure it out before we agreed to meet tomorrow to try and get it to work.

Below is what I have come up with so far to see tomorrow if it fixes the issue:

1. Added 'bind-address = 0.0.0.0' to the my.ini file directly underneath the [mysql] section
2. Created a root2 user for my partner to use in place of root user in his connection code with host as % instead of localhost with command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON events.* TO 'root2'@'%';` on the mysql command line
3. Adjusted firewall settings to account for port 3306

Would the last step be to change my partner's `host: 'localhost'` to the ip address of my machine? Would it be easier/necessary for my partner to connect using MySQL workbench or does he need to download anything else for it to work?

Comment: If you're behind a NAT router, he needs to use its public IP, and the router needs port forwarding of port 3306.

Comment: How he connects is the same whether he's using Workbench or node.js.

Comment: @Barmar thank you we'll try that tomorrow morning.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the error log for your MySQL server.
2. Select the host user from `mysql.user`.
3. Check your `firewalld(linux)`, then  shutdown. Check `my.ini(windows) bind-address`.